# Why does pip not install the .whl version of a package on alpine base?

Tags: python

While trying to roll a docker-in-docker image, I'm running up against an issue where certain python modules are not being installed by their pre-compiled `.whl` variants, instead they are trying to be source compiled.  In this particular case it's Pandas and consequently NumPy:

```
FROM docker:dind

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    mtr \
    tcpdump \
    bind-tools \
    iputils \
    python3 \
    py3-pip \
    git \
```

This Dockerfile gives me an x86_64 container with Python 3.10.11:

```bash
/workspaces/ariobot # uname -a
Linux a76ba19d56af 5.15.49-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue Sep 13 07:51:46 UTC 2022 x86_64 Linux
/workspaces/ariobot # python -V
Python 3.10.11
/workspaces/ariobot #
```

According to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.5.3/#modal-close) there is `pandas-1.5.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl` which I am assuming is compatible, but it doesn't seem to be retrieving it:

```
/workspaces/ariobot # pip install pandas==1.5.3
Collecting pandas==1.5.3
  Downloading pandas-1.5.3.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.2/5.2 MB 26.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [282 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=51.0.0
        Downloading setuptools-67.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
           ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 15.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting wheel
        Downloading wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
           ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 64.5/64.5 kB 14.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.32
        Downloading Cython-0.29.34-cp310-cp310-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl (2.0 MB)
           ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.0/2.0 MB 34.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16
        Downloading oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.21.6
        Downloading numpy-1.21.6.zip (10.3 MB)
           ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.3/10.3 MB 54.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [248 lines of output]
            setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.6 may not yet support Python 3.10.
              warnings.warn(
            Running from numpy source directory.
```

The output above also shows it trying to install NumPy 1.21.6 from source, despite [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.21.6/#files) showing a 3.10/x86_64/anylinux `.whl` variant being available.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The reason pip is not installing the `.whl` version of a package like pandas on an Alpine-based image is that Alpine Linux uses a different C library called musl-libc, while the `manylinux2014_x86_64` wheels are built against the GNU C Library (glibc). The `manylinux2014_x86_64` wheels are not compatible with Alpine due to this difference in the underlying C library.